# How to I amend Unix shell script to Windows batch file?

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, unix

I need to convert the following Unix script to run on Windows. I'm assuming the `cd` commands would be changed to call `dir` and the `echo` commands changed to call `print`.

The script checks a directory for a given file, if the file is not present then the script loops/sleeps and then checks again.

I'm mainly struggling how best to convert the variables and the loop command, any tips/hints would be appreciated?

```
cd $DIRECTORY_NAME

echo "You are currently in $(pwd) directory"

numfiles=0

while [ $numfiles -lt "1" ]

do

    export filename=`ls SWIX_BAU_success`
    export numfiles=$(echo $filename | wc -w)
    echo "$numfiles file found"

if [ $numfiles -ge "1" ]

then

    echo "$filename file found"
    exit 0

else

    echo "Incorrect number of files found, 1 file expected"
    numfiles=0
    sleep 300

fi

done
```

Comment: SS64 has decent references on both [Windows batch (`cmd`)](https://ss64.com/nt) and [`bash`](https://ss64.com/bash/). You might want to check them out before doing your conversion; you might also want to consider using PowerShell instead of Windows batch.

Comment: Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/354577)

Answer (score 0):

I was just about posting this answer on SO when you revoked the question.
Assuming `SWIX_BAU_success` is a (sub)directory with only one file.

```
@Echo off

cd /D "%DIRECTORY_NAME%"
echo You are currently in directory: %CD%
Set numfiles=0

For /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%A in (
    'Dir /B "SWIX_BAU_success" ^| findstr /n ^ '
) DO Set numfiles=%%a&Set filename=%%B

If %numfiles% equ 1 (
    echo %filename% found
    exit /B 0
) else (
    echo "Incorrect number of files found, 1 file expected"
    set numfiles=0
    Timeout /T 300
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this looks great and i'll be testing it shortly.  Regarding your assumption, `SWIX_BAU_success` is the file name and not a directory and yes there will only be one file. 

The directory containing the file is where you have `cd /D "%DIRECTORY_NAME%"`

Comment: If it is a distinct file name which could exist only once this reduces to a simple `if exist "SWIX_BAU_success" (..) Else (...)`